# how to sort the result by pandas.value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to count the number of student who got 0-5 grade in one dataset

I use this function `final_grade_num =pd.value_counts(final_grade)` to get a result like

```
4.0    487
3.0    432
2.0    376
5.0    334
1.0    232
0.0    139
```

however, I want to get a sorted list like

```
0.0 139, 1.0 232...5.0 334
```

because I need to use this dataset to draw a plot

```
plt.bar(range(0,6), final_grade_num)
```

Is there any method to change, I tried to use sorted method, but the result shows it depends on the number of students, not grade

Comment: just chain with `sort_values`

Comment: `final_grade.value_counts().plot()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`value_counts()` has a `sort` argument that defaults to `True`. Just set it to `False` and it will be sorted by value instead.

```
df['col'].value_counts(sort = False).plot.bar(title='My Title')
```

Or:

```
df['col'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

Comment: thanks but I didn't understand of df['col'] meaning and where do I put 'final_grade_num' as parameter?

Comment: `df` is the name of your dataframe, and `col` is the column you want to use. because i don't know the specific names of your dataframe and columns

Comment: thank you again but how to show the plot, I use "data['grades'].value_counts(sort = False).plot.bar(title='final grade')"   but there is no image here, this is my first time to see this method. Is it base on matplotlib or others?

Comment: I think `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `plt.show()` would do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but why the x-label is vertical not horizontal? how to change these parameters? I find plot.bar() even don't have 'title' parameter but it can work.

Comment: The ```sort_index()``` saved me, thanks!